# javascript: find correct index to place object in sorted array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a `getSortedIndex` function. The function accepts the following arguments:

1. An array of objects which are sorted by a key.
2. A new object to be inserted into the array.
3. The key by which all objects are sorted.

```
function getSortedIndex(array, objToInsert, key) {
    var low = 0,
    high = array.length,
    value = objToInsert[key];

    while (low < high) {
        var mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        if (value > array[mid][key]) low = mid + 1;
        else high = mid;
    }
    return low;
}
```

When the function is called, it returns the index at which the object should be placed into the array:

```
var sorted_array_of_objects = [
    { 'x': 20 },
    // The new object will be placed here.
    { 'x': 30 },
    { 'x': 30 },
    { 'x': 40 },
    { 'x': 50 }
];
var objectToInsert = { 'x': 30, y: 10 };

getSortedIndex(sorted_array_of_objects, objectToInsert, 'x'); //=> 1
```

### My question

Can you modify the function so it returns the index that would place the new object *after* the objects in the array that have the same value for the `x` property? If there are no objects in the array with the same value for the `x` property, then the normal sort index should be returned.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/sortedIndex/3/edit?javascript,console,output

Comment: I think your function is incomplete. You missed some code. Where is `mid` defined? What's with the `;` after `while (low >> 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like all you have to do is change the comparison from

```
if (value > array[mid][key])
```

to

```
if (value >= array[mid][key])
```

so that keeps comparing elements with the same value.

Comment: I added a demo to my question, tried your change and it didn't work.

Comment: +1 Take that back, I thought you were telling me to switch out a different operator. You're a genius!